# Is there out-of-the-box test support for WebAuthenticationDetails?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Some of our access voters need access to the WebAuthenticationDetails of the Authentication.

Does Spring Security provides out-of-the-box support for providing and associating the WebAuthenticationDetails with the Authentication in test cases? I noticed that @WithMockUser or @WithUserDetails don't fill in the WebAuthenticationDetails for example.

What is the recommended and/or best way to implement this functionality in tests?

If there is no standard way, do I need to provide my own RequestPostProcessor?

I'm using Spring Security 4.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, for now I use a custom RequestPostProcessor, something like:

```
static RequestPostProcessor webAuthenticationDetails() {
    return new WebAuthenticationDetailsPostProcessor();
}

static RequestPostProcessor webAuthenticationDetails(String remoteIpAddress) {
    return new WebAuthenticationDetailsPostProcessor(remoteIpAddress);
}

private static class WebAuthenticationDetailsPostProcessor implements RequestPostProcessor {

    private final String remoteIpAddress;

    public WebAuthenticationDetailsPostProcessor() {
        this(null);
    }

    public WebAuthenticationDetailsPostProcessor(String remoteIpAddress) {
        this.remoteIpAddress = remoteIpAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        if (context != null) {
            Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
            if (authentication instanceof AbstractAuthenticationToken) {
                if (remoteIpAddress != null) {
                    request.setRemoteAddr(remoteIpAddress);
                }
                ((AbstractAuthenticationToken) authentication).setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
            }
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

Perhaps something like this should be part of Spring Security Test?